# Convert XHR (XML Http Request) into R command

Tags: r, xmlhttprequest, httr

I am trying to turn an XHR (XMLHttpRequest) request into an R command.

I am using the following code:

```
library(httr)
x <- POST("https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/actualGenerationPerGenerationUnit/getDataTableDetailData/?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=17.03.2017+00%3A00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&dateTime.endDateTime=17.03.2017+00%3A00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&area.values=CTY%7C10YBE----------2!BZN%7C10YBE----------2&productionType.values=B02&productionType.values=B03&productionType.values=B04&productionType.values=B05&productionType.values=B06&productionType.values=B07&productionType.values=B08&productionType.values=B09&productionType.values=B10&productionType.values=B11&productionType.values=B12&productionType.values=B13&productionType.values=B14&productionType.values=B20&productionType.values=B15&productionType.values=B16&productionType.values=B17&productionType.values=B18&productionType.values=B19&dateTime.timezone=UTC&dateTime.timezone_input=UTC&dv-datatable-detail_22WAMERCO000010Y_22WAMERCO000008L_length=10&dv-datatable_length=50&detailId=22WAMERCO000010Y_22WAMERCO000008L",
         user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.50 Safari/537.36"),
         add_headers(`Referer`="https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/actualGenerationPerGenerationUnit/show?name=&defaultValue=true&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=17.03.2017+00:00|UTC|DAYTIMERANGE&dateTime.endDateTime=17.03.2017+00:00|UTC|DAYTIMERANGE&area.values=CTY|10YBE----------2!BZN|10YBE----------2&productionType.values=B02&productionType.values=B03&productionType.values=B04&productionType.values=B05&productionType.values=B06&productionType.values=B07&productionType.values=B08&productionType.values=B09&productionType.values=B10&productionType.values=B11&productionType.values=B12&productionType.values=B13&productionType.values=B14&productionType.values=B15&productionType.values=B16&productionType.values=B17&productionType.values=B18&productionType.values=B19&productionType.values=B20&dateTime.timezone=UTC&dateTime.timezone_input=UTC&dv-datatable_length=100",
                     Connection = "keep-alive",
                     Host = "https://transparency.entsoe.eu/",
                     Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                     `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate, br",
                     Origin = "https://transparency.entsoe.eu",
                     `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest",
                     `Content-Type` = "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                     `Accept-Language`= "en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6,fr-FR;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2"))
```

But I keep getting an 400 error: bad request instead of the 200 which would mark a successful response.

I've extracted the values via the Chrome network monitor from [this website](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/actualGenerationPerGenerationUnit/show?name=&defaultValue=true&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=17.03.2017%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&dateTime.endDateTime=17.03.2017%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAYTIMERANGE&area.values=CTY%7C10YBE----------2!BZN%7C10YBE----------2&productionType.values=B02&productionType.values=B03&productionType.values=B04&productionType.values=B05&productionType.values=B06&productionType.values=B07&productionType.values=B08&productionType.values=B09&productionType.values=B10&productionType.values=B11&productionType.values=B12&productionType.values=B13&productionType.values=B14&productionType.values=B15&productionType.values=B16&productionType.values=B17&productionType.values=B18&productionType.values=B19&productionType.values=B20&dateTime.timezone=UTC&dateTime.timezone_input=UTC&dv-datatable_length=100). The XHR request is sent when the plus button is clicked. I can send it repeatedly from my browser, but it doesn't seem to work from R.

What am I doing wrong in creating the Post request?

Comment: Most likely the web page markup loads on user interaction. So when R requests it fails to return the markup of your interest. The solution would be use RSelenium.

Comment: There is a transparency.entsoe.eu API with a guide (https://transparency.entsoe.eu/content/static_content/Static%20content/web%20api/Guide.html).

Comment: @AleksandrVoitov Is it not possible to capture this markup in the request?

Comment: @bergant Yes, but not for this specific property

Comment: @takje I was looking at chapter _4.4.5. Actual Generation Output per Generation Unit ( [16.1.A])_ - maybe not the same thing.

Comment: @bergant I was looking for the consumption data of the plants. So far I haven't found it in the API. I already tried playing with the PSRtype to load but that doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: @takje What is your link to the site you want to scrape? The following you posted in a POST request does not work.

Comment: @AleksandrVoitov I am trying to scrape the consumption data that is shown when you click on the plus symbol next to each plant. I've noticed that there is a small XHR request when you click on this + symbol. Therefore I was trying to recreate this request.

Comment: This link is a better link for the consumption data: https://transparency.entsoe.eu/generation/r2/actualGenerationPerGenerationUnit/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=02.02.2017+00:00|UTC|DAYTIMERANGE&dateTime.endDateTime=02.02.2017+00:00|UTC|DAYTIMERANGE&area.values=CTY|10YFR-RTE------C!BZN|10YFR-RTE------C&productionType.values=B10&dateTime.timezone=UTC&dateTime.timezone_input=UTC&dv-datatable_length=100